# Total revenue of an account for the preceding 12 months - Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

So my doubt is in sql. I am looking to find the total revenue of a parent account for the last 12 months.
The data will look something like this

| revenue | name | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | abc | 201001 | 2010-01-12 |
| 10000 | abc | 201402 | 2014-02-14 |
| 2000 | abc | 201404 | 2014-04-12 |
| 3000 | abc | 201406 | 2014-06-30 |
| 30000 | def | 201301 | 2013-01-14 |
| 6000 | def | 201304 | 2013-04-12 |
| 9000 | def | 201407 | 2013-07-19 |

And the output should be something like this

| revenue | name | month | year | Running Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | abc | 201001 | 2010-01-12 | 10000 |
| 10000 | abc | 201402 | 2014-02-14 | 10000 |
| 2000 | abc | 201404 | 2014-04-12 | 12000 |
| 3000 | abc | 201406 | 2014-06-30 | 15000 |
| 30000 | def | 201301 | 2013-01-14 | 30000 |
| 6000 | def | 201304 | 2013-04-12 | 36000 |
| 9000 | def | 201407 | 2013-07-19 | 45000 |

I have tried using using windowing function something like this and the logic that I need

```
select revenue, name, date, month,
sum(revenue) over (partition by name order by month rows between '12 months' preceding AND CURRENT ROW )
from table
```

but the above command gives a syntax error

Comment: so sorry, I am using redshift. I'll update it!

Comment: `order by month range between current row and interval '12 months'` means "from current row inclusively and all next rows till a year later". Use `FROM PRECEDING INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND CURRENT ROW` (or maybe 11 month?)...

Comment: Hi, I am still getting a syntax error for this. Probably redshift does not support interval command. I saw that in their documentation as well

Answer (score 0):

Redshift does not support intervals in the window frame specification.

So, convert to a number.  A convenient one in this case is the number of months since some point in time:

```
select revenue, name, date, month,
       sum(revenue) over (partition by name
                          order by datediff(month, '1900-01-01', month)
                          range between 12 preceding and current row
                         )
from table;
```

I will note that your logic adds up data from 13 months, not 12.  I suspect you want `between 11 preceding and current row`.

You can use `rows between` if you have data for all months:

```
       sum(revenue) over (partition by name
                          order by datediff(month, '1900-01-01', month)
                          rows between 12 preceding and current row
                         )
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! the solutions looks great. I just have one problem, I am getting a syntax error like this   "RANGE clause of window functions not yet implemented", do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, the number of months are not fixed, also there might be multiple revenue of the name in a single month . So I can't really hardcode the number 11 preceding.